# How to see Nginx log?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

When I want to see the Gunicorn log to see if I have any errors, I do `gunicorn --log-file=- <my_app>.wsgi:application` - what command do I use to see the Nginx log?

Comment: your nginx log will be available at the location you have specified in nginx config file, something like this access_log  /var/log/nginx/app.xxx.in.log  main;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/app.xxx.in.log;

Comment: I don't have and `log`-like variable in my nginx config file :/ (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp` Any idea?

Comment: by default all error log will go to /var/logs/error.log.

Comment: I just looked inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available/app` and it says this: `location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }` Does this mean I disabled `access_log`? EDIT: I just accessed `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf ` - could this be where my error log is?

Comment: access_log off mean nginx will not log your request, moreover did you check in /var/logs/ folder??